# How to sum two dimensional arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I've created a short code to practice two-dimensional arrays but I've stumbled upon a problem that I can't solve in my code. Hope you guys can help me.

**Desired Output:**

Enter number:1
Enter number:2
Enter number:3

NUMBERS THAT YOU ENTERED:
1
2
3

TOTAL: 6

Enter number:1
Enter number:2
Enter number:3

NUMBERS THAT YOU ENTERED:
1
2
3

TOTAL: 6

**But instead I'm seeing this:**

Enter number:1
Enter number:2
Enter number:3

NUMBERS THAT YOU ENTERED:
1
2
3

TOTAL: 6

Enter number:1
Enter number:2
Enter number:3

NUMBERS THAT YOU ENTERED:
1
2
3

TOTAL: 12

### ______________________________________________________

It's adding up every number that I input instead of just adding three numbers in each iteration. Please check the code below:

***PART I***

```
package Test;

 public class Test1 {
   private int[][] number;
   private int number1;
   public Test1(int[][]n){
      number = new int[2][3];
    for(int dx = 0;dx < number.length;dx++){
        for(int ix = 0;ix < number[dx].length;ix++){
            number[dx][ix]=n[dx][ix];
        }
        
    }
}

public Test1(int n){
    number1 = n;
}

public int getTotal(){
    int total = 0;
    
    for(int dx = 0;dx < number.length;dx++){
        for(int ix = 0;ix < number[dx].length;ix++){
            total += number[dx][ix];
        }
        
    }
    
    return total;
}

public int getNumbers(){

    return number1;
}

}
```

***PART II***

```
  package Test;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class TestMain {
  public static void main(String[]args){
    final int DIVS = 2;
    final int NUM_INSIDE = 3;
    Test1[][] t1 = new Test1[DIVS][NUM_INSIDE];
    int[][]numbers = new int[DIVS][NUM_INSIDE];
    getValues(numbers,DIVS,NUM_INSIDE,t1);
    
}

public static void getValues(int[][]numbers,int DIVS,int NUM_INSIDE,Test1[][] t1){
    Scanner hold = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;
    for(int div = 0;div < DIVS;div++){
        for(int ins = 0;ins < NUM_INSIDE;ins++){
            System.out.print("Enter number:");
            numbers[div][ins]=hold.nextInt();
            num = numbers[div][ins];
            t1[div][ins] = new Test1(num);
            
        }
        Test1 t = new Test1(numbers);
        display(t,t1,div);
        
    }
}

public static void display(Test1 t,Test1[][] t1,int div){
    System.out.print("****************************\n");
    System.out.print("NUMBERS THAT YOU ENTERED:\n");
    
    for(int y = 0; y < t1[div].length;y++){
        System.out.print(t1[div][y].getNumbers() + "\n");
    }
    
    System.out.print("****************************\n");
    System.out.print("TOTAL: " + t.getTotal() + "\n");
    System.out.print("****************************\n");
}
}
```

Comment: IS YOUR CAPSLOCK STUCK?

Comment: All caps is considered screaming, we don't tolerate them.

Comment: Also consider that this code only works for a maximum div dimension of [2][3] because of the hardcoded initialization in Test1: number = new int[2][3]

Answer (score 1):

Your getTotal method sums up all elements of your 2-d array. So consider passing a variable to the method so as to indicate which row of your 2d array you want to evaluate.So your getTotal method can be something like this :

```
public int getTotal(int row){
int total = 0;   
    for(int ix = 0;ix < number[row].length;ix++){
        total += number[row][ix];
    }

}

return total;
```

}

In your main function you can keep track of the row no by using a counter variable. Finally call the getTotal method with row no.

```
 System.out.print("TOTAL: " + t.getTotal(div) + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getTotal()` method sums all the values in the 2D array. After reading the first input row, the second row still contains default values (0s), so you get the sum of the elements in the first row.

After reading the second input row, you get the total sum of both rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum all numbers in the 2d array, you should replace `getValues` with this method

```
public static void getValues(int[][]numbers,int DIVS,int NUM_INSIDE,Test1[][] t1){
  Scanner hold = new Scanner(System.in);
  int num;
  Test1 t;
  for(int div = 0;div < DIVS;div++){
      for(int ins = 0;ins < NUM_INSIDE;ins++){
          System.out.print("Enter number:");
          numbers[div][ins]=hold.nextInt();
          num = numbers[div][ins];
          t1[div][ins] = new Test1(num);

      }
  }
  // out of loops
  t = new Test1(numbers);
  display(t,t1,DIVS-1);
}
```

but if you want to sum numbers in each row please see answer of @Sourav Kanta